# Почему не находит элемент по id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Элемент создается через react portal

```js
import { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const CollectionPreviewItem = ( { component } ) => {
  const el = useMemo ( () =>(
    document.createElement ( 'div' )
), [] );
  el.setAttribute( 'id', 'portal' );
  useEffect ( () => {
    document.body.appendChild ( el );
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild ( el );
    };
  }, [ el ] );

  return (
    createPortal ( component, el )
  );
};

export default CollectionPreviewItem;
```

```js
const CollectionPreviewItem = ( { key, item } ) => {
  const removeElem = () =>{
    let a =  document.getElementById('portal');
    console.log(a);
  };
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation ();
  return (
    <CollectionPreviewItemContainer>
      <CollectionPreviewItemHeader>
        <CollectionPreviewItemTitle>Collection Preview Item</CollectionPreviewItemTitle>
        <CloseIconWrapper onClick ={removeElem()} >
          <CloseIcon />
        </CloseIconWrapper>
      </CollectionPreviewItemHeader>

      <CollectionPreviewItemImage  />
    </CollectionPreviewItemContainer>
  );
};

export default CollectionPreviewItem;
```

console.log возращает null
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очевидно вы вызываете console.log раньше чем был сгенерирован portal

Comment: согласен с предыдущим комментарием: пытаетесь получить document.getElementById('portal') при рендере; попробуйте получать в useEffect() когда происходит событие componentDidMount

Comment: `document.createElement('div')` это вы сами написали?

Comment: @ Избыток Сусликов да

Comment: Собственно, я не совсем понял, вижу два компонента с одинаковым именем `CollectionPreviewItem`, в первом создается элемент `portal` при монтировании и удаляется при размонтировании, а во втором - удаляется при нажатии на кнопку. Так может элемент у вас не найден и вы видите `null` потому что уже произошло размонтирование первого? Да и не совсем понятно, почему имена одинаковые, это заводит в заблуждение.